# URL is not opening in WKWebView in swift

Tags: webview, wkwebview, swift5, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a requirement to open the URL in **WKWebView** and login to the portal. As user logged in successfully after that I have to perform download operation from WKWebView, Everything is working fine but it's opening in external safari browser but as per requirement it should open in WKWebView

Outlet for WKWebView

```
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
```

Function to call URL in WKWebVIew

```
   func loadURLInWebView() {
   let url = URL(string: "https://www-qa.yyy.com/content/dash/en/public/login.html")
   let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
   if let webView = webView {
       webView.load(urlRequest)
   }
}
```

after adding decidePolicyFor delegate it's opening url in safari but it should open in WKWebView. I am not able to find the issue.

```
 public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let url = navigationAction.request.url
    guard url != nil else {
        print(url!)
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }

    if url!.description.lowercased().starts(with: "http://") ||
        url!.description.lowercased().starts(with: "https://")  {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are handling guard statement in the wrong way. In guard else, the condition will be called when the URL is nil.
**If you do print(URL!)  in else your app will crash**. moreover when URL is nill, you should call cancel Handler.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else { // else will be called when url is nil
       decisionHandler(.cancel)
       return
    }

    if url.description.lowercased().starts(with: "http://") ||
       url.description.lowercased().starts(with: "https://")  {
           decisionHandler(.allow)
    } else {
          decisionHandler(.cancel)
           UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response  but now downloading stoped working....

Comment: what is your download URL ?